# Charging a capacitor at high voltage

Tags: high-voltage

I succeeded in making a small high voltage arc without using electronics components (diodes, transistors,.. ) using this diagram:
motor turn on & off a switch connected to power supply and homemade HV transformer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9ES3W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I simulate this setup, it generate positive and negative arcs. This means that the output will not charge a HV capacitor.

1. Is there a way to get only one sign pulses (+arc or -arc) , (without using HV diode or flyback)?
2. Is there any way to make a working HV diode?

The goal is charging a HV capacitor at its maximum voltage (several hundred kV with any way).
I want to raise the voltage more so I want to attach the output of the first transformer to the primary of tesla coil.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fykyWS.png)</sup>

3. Will the result of tesla coil charge the capacitor?
4. Do I need HV diode to charge HV capacitor?
5. Is there any way to rise voltage at maximum?

Comment: drawing this by hand must have been so much more exhausting than using the built-in schematic editor...

Comment: sorry for that , I will edit

Comment: The traditional approach for HV charging is things like a Cockroft-Walton multiplier or a van der Graaf generator.

Comment: @pjc50 thank you , but those needs dc hv

Comment: The Cockcroft-Walton multiplier can start at low voltages.  It requires **AC** for its input.  The Van de Graaf generator **makes** high voltage DC.  You can drive it with anything mechanical - a hand crank if you like, or an electric motor of some kind.  Or run off a gasoline engine.  It doesn't care.

Comment: @JRE Cockcroft-Walton multiplier needs many diodes , I think van de graaf generator cant charge a capacitor

Comment: [A Van de Graaf generator has a capacitor as part of its structure.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator) - and there's no reason you couldn't connect a capacitor to it.

Comment: [You might also look into a Wimshurst machine.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wimshurst_machine)   High voltage, can charge capacitors - they usually have a couple of them (Leyden jars) built in.

Comment: @JRE thank you very much , I will try Wimshurst machine , is there any other methods to get +or- hv ?